# Solve nonlinear equation

Tags: matlab, equation, solver

I am having some problems with my function code. The main idea is to get parameter `SI` (main unknown) in which the equation `Q_cal-Q=0`. Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot.

```
P=1.94;
Q=1.09;
P5=1.08;
fc=0;
lambda=0.2;
Ts=24;

[SI]=singhandyu(P,Q,P5,lambda,Ts,fc);


    function [SI] =singhandyu(P,Q,P5,lambda,Ts,fc)

    Fc=fc.*Ts; 

f=@(SI)((P5-0.2*SI)*SI)./(P5+0.8*SI);
M=@(SI)max(f(SI),0);
S=@(SI)(SI-M(SI));

Ia=@(SI)lambda.*S(SI);
Q_cal=@(SI)((P-Ia(SI)-Fc).*(P-Ia(SI)-Fc+M(SI)))./(P-Ia(SI)-Fc+M(SI)+S(SI));

H=@(SI)Q_cal(SI)-Q;
S0=0;
SI_sol=fsolve(H,S0)
end
```

Comment: Please explain what the problems are. See [ask].

Comment: Matlab displays the following error: Undefined operator '-' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Comment: Can you show how you call the function, in the form of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex), so define all the inputs (with some random data if needed).

Comment: In the upper part I added the way I'm calling the function with its values.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all your anonymous functions need `SI` as an input, but you are not passing the argument when you call a previously defined function.

To clarify, `f` requires one input argument,

```
f=@(SI)((P5-0.2*SI)*SI)./(P5+0.8*SI);
```

but when calling `f` in the next line, you are not providing it:

```
M=@(SI)max(f,0);
```

So make sure you pass the argument to each function call:

```
M=@(SI)max(f(SI),0);
S=@(SI)max(SI-M(SI),0);
```

etc.

Comment: The previous problem is solved, but now as a solution I am getting zero. Here is the code: Fc=fc.*Ts; 

f=@(SI)((P5-0.2*SI)*SI)./(P5+0.8*SI);
M=@(SI)max(f(SI),0);
S=@(SI)(SI-M(SI));

Ia=@(SI)lambda.*S(SI);
Q_cal=@(SI)((P-Ia(SI)-Fc).*(P-Ia(SI)-Fc+M(SI)))./(P-Ia(SI)-Fc+M(SI)+S(SI));

H=@(SI)Q_cal(SI)-Q;
S0=0;
SI_sol=fsolve(H,S0)

Comment: @RicardoAndresAzuero, could you please add your new updated code to your question body by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56155942/edit) your question? This is not very readable